# Ext.Container height and width on 100 percent

Tags: extjs

**I am using extjs 3.4**

I would like to have a container, which occupies 100 percent height and width of the screen. Inside that container I have only two panels, each with 50% height and 100% width.

I really don't know what am I doing wrong here? I can specify width and height of each component in pixels, but I would like to set percent. How to do this?

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

        var ct = new Ext.Container({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            style: 'background-color: pink;',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            items:[
                {
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch',
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'first panel',
                        flex: .5
                    },{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'second panel',
                        flex: .5
                    }]
                }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use '[ViewPost](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Viewport)', something like:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var viewPort = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'first panel'
        }, {
            title: 'second panel'
        }]
    });

});
```